# Webdriverio: including common elements between multiple page objects

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Using webdriver-io's suggested page object pattern, what's the best way to include a module containing elements common to multiple pages, eg. a search box, or nav bar?

For example...

myPage

```
var basePage = require('./basePage');
var searchModule = require('./searchModule');

var myPage = Object.create(basePage, {
    search: { value: Object.create(this, searchModule) },
    ...
```

searchModule

```
var searchModule = {
    searchBox: { get: function() { return browser.element('input#s'); }},

    searchFor: { value: function(searchText) {
        this.searchBox.setValue(searchText);
        browser.keys('Enter');
    }}
```

This works, and allows usage like: `myPage.search.searchFor('some text');` but is this the best (or even a good) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got it right  I would keep any functions that will be used on multiple pages in the base page. Since all page objects require base page, you will always have access to them and not need to write duplicate methods.